# Several error in equation typing

Tags: equations, r

This is my equation.

```
\begin{equation}
E$\epsilon$$\epsilon$=V$_$$\epsilon\$=$\Omega$
\end{equation}
```

- 

```
These are the errors that I'm receiving
Dispaly math should end with $$
Missing $ inserted
Missing { inserted 
Missing } inserted 
You can't use \eqno in math mode
```

- 

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove all the `$` signs within the `equation` environment.

Comment: thanks!!! that was really fast&helpful

Comment: How did you get that code output in the first place? From R, sure, but through what? Rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1):

However to construct the `equation`, possibly within R, you should remove the `$` signs, as they initiate math mode - something already done by the environment and therefore the cause of your error(s).